# Auto delete rows from log table in mysql db with a trigger

Tags: sql, mysql, logging, triggers

Can someone provide me with a mysql 5 trigger creation code that would allow me to delete the first x number of rows in a table when the total number of rows in my table reaches y ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform any CRUD on the same table that fires the trigger... ergo this cannot be done using a trigger on the table

You can however use a sequence of two queries.  Since it is a log table, it may or may not matter if the 2nd one failed.  Once in a while, count the total rows and trim it to size again.

```
INSERT INTO LOGTABLE .....   # 1 record
DELETE FROM LOGTABLE ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;
```

**EDITED:** for a better workaround

A more sensible alternative is to schedule a job (windows task scheduler + mysql.exe `or` linux + cron) that will run this batch, which preserves only 100 (change to suit) records

```
set @sql := (select count(*) from logtable) - 100;
set @sql := concat('delete from logtable order by date limit ', @sql);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: is there no way of scheduling this? Performing a delete at every insert seems a little costly to me resourcewise. Maybe I've got the triggers concept wrong?

Comment: Yes, triggers won't work. But I have edited answer with what should be a better method

Comment: that is perfect - thank you so mucht. I've thought a bit about this, and to be auto-scalable as more users take use of the site and more logs are logged, I think it'd be better if logs older than 1 month were deleted.